# Calling a POST request in reacts componentWillRecieveProps

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, axios

I'm attempting to submit a POST request in a react lifecycle method to save to my database.

My componentWillReceiveProps looks like this:

```
// Update location when user logs in
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (this.props.user.username !== nextProps.user.username) {
      if( navigator && navigator.geolocation ) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((pos) => {
          const { latitude, longitude } = pos.coords;
          this.setState({
            currentLocation: { lat: latitude, lng: longitude }
          });
          // save location...
          this.saveLocation(latitude, longitude);
        });
      }
    }
  }



  // Save to Database
  saveLocation(lat, lng) {
    console.log('saving.....');
    axios.post('/location', { lat, lng })
      .then((response) => {
        console.log("saved");
      }).catch((error) => {
        console.log('not saved', error);
      });
  }
```

The post request above will refuse to connect to my server. The strange thing is I am able to run saveLocation in the componentDidMount, and same post request will work when POSTing via curl. Am I missing something imperative when working with ajax and react. Any advise would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the content of the error in your console?

Comment: not saved Error: Network Error  
    
    at createError (createError.js?f777:16)
    
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js?14ed:87)

Comment: Could be a CORS config problem on your server, NGINX?